# Android-Helloworld app / not clear

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I created a regular blank main activity instead on the blank fragment layout activity this generated the R.java files... etc

Now R.java cannot be edited & MainActivitiy.java classes 
- R.java file has id / menu / dimen classes missing
- MainActivity.java gives error for 
     (setcontentview(...R.layout... )) 
     getMenuinflate(...R.menu...) 
as these classes dont exist in R.java

I commented the lines and all error free - HELLO WORLD runs - now the AVD loads the apk but - message "unfortunate things happen..." - i get a message in the AVD saying this "has crashed..."

The cycle is not clear - neither in the tutorial nor the ebooks

Question: Why Fragment layout instead of activit_main.xml?
Question:R.java is my biggest enemy - cus i cant modify or use it...

Following = TUTORIALS POINT - SIMPLY EASY LEARNING TUT...

Comment: "R.java is my biggest enemy - cus i cant modify or use it". You should not edit R.java. R is auto-generated. If you add an extra String to Strings.xml, it will be added to R.java the next time it is generated.

Comment: If you let us what you want to learn we can send you to an appropriate tutorial.

Comment: Android mobile apps development - fast track - with skeleton barebone projects - basic implementation & guide to files in the code to understand project flow , syntax / events / code constructs etc I will add as needed and learn...

Answer (score 2):

Do not edit the R file. It is generated by the Android compiler. It is difficult to tell what you have done, so instead of fixing it, start over. You're attempting to create a HelloWorld app, correct? Just create a new application in eclipse, blank activity and all. You're good to go from there.

Comment: Thats exactly what was created - but the R.java has - classes - id/menu/dimen -  missing....

Comment: There are other tutorials - complete running code components - with complete r.java / with id / menu / layout and dimen classes - how can i be expected to start a project on existing apps...

Comment: Common fixes to misbehaving R files are : restarting eclipse and going to Project -> Clean. See if that works.

Comment: I importing existing code - from another tutorial- it works, however i am not clear what R.java - containing all the stuff we need and not editable? serves purpose...